# VS2015 Missing Breakpoint Toolbar Icons

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, my "Enable All Breakpoint" and "Disable All Breakpoint" toolbar button icons are missing.

I've seen some topics about ALL icons being missing, (and installed the VSUpdate Fix for that) but my issue seems to be just those two. I'm presuming they ARE actually supposed to have icons in VS2015? They do in VS2010 at least.

[Missing Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uowbZ.png)

Comment: They've fixed this now in update 2. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the icons were removed between 2010 and 2015. I don't see a way to get them back, but you can change the toolbar so that it shows text instead of the icon by changing "Default Style" to "Text Always" in the "Modify Selection" drop down list:

[image]

Then the toolbar looks like this, which is at least better than the empty icons in your screenshot:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: lol WAT, they've actually removed the icons? I presume this is a bug or something. I can't see why they'd not have icons for buttons on the standard bloody toolbar. I saw the ability to enable text yeah. Bit weird they'd just leave a big gaping hole in the toolbar. 2010 certainly has relevant icons for them.